# Javascript one function validate same form checkbox group and radio button group

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm Javascript beginner, writing JS function to validate a radio button group and a checkbox group; if either of them are completely unchecked, respective alert(s) show and stop the form submitting.

I copied code for radio button group validation, then adjusted it by adding a 2nd 'splitter' function which takes radio and checkbox names as 2 arguments, then sends both names in sequence to the 'validate' function.

This works, but is there more compact way to do this in one function, JS version of select case or something?

```
  <script>

  function splitter(mainst, Cst) {
  validate(mainst);
  validate(Cst);
  }

//'unchecked' counts number of unchecked boxes or buttons
//then compares this to total number in the group, and if same
//this means nothing is checked, therefore show alert and return false.
      function validate(grpname) {
      var unchecked = 0, selectgroup=document.getElementsByName(grpname)
      for(i=0;i<selectgroup.length;i++) {
      if(selectgroup.item(i).checked == false) {
      unchecked++;
      }
      }
      if(unchecked == selectgroup.length) {
        if (grpname == 'mainstreet') {
        alert("Please select a main street");
        return false;
        }
        else {
        alert("Please select your C street(s)");
        return false;
        }
      } else {
      return true;
      }
      }

      </script>
```

Example form here:

```
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return splitter('mainstreet', 'Cstreet')">
  Street:
  <input type="radio" name="mainstreet" value="jones"> jones street
  <input type="radio" name="mainstreet" value="bones"> bones street
  <input type="radio" name="mainstreet" value="drones"> drones street
  <input type="radio" name="mainstreet" value="foobar"> foobar street
  <br /><br />
  Side street:
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cstreet" value="barfoo"> barfoo street
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cstreet" value="candoo"> candoo street
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cstreet" value="cantdo"> cantdo street
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cstreet" value="canoe"> canoe street
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cstreet" value="wahoo"> wahoo street

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function splitter(mainst, Cst) {
    if(document.querySelector('input[name="'+mainst+'"]:checked') == null ){
        alert("Please select a main street");
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.querySelector('input[name="'+Cst+'"]:checked') == null) {
        alert("Please select your C street(s)");
        return false;
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent thanks @Rajat, looked two blogs for my code, both much longer than your method using querySelector, also for some reason my original JS code did not stop my real form submitting, but with your code, the return falses do stop submit event :-) I don't know why.